# Python 2.7 MySQLdb to save last row read from database into text file

Tags: python, mysql, excel, python-2.7

I have been tasked with getting a MySQL database to send data into Salesforce and create a ticket. I currently have python downloading the required tables from the database and saving that information into a .xlsx sheet. Then I have another python script uploading that data to a Google Doc sheet and then a Javascript trigger that will submit the data into salesforce and all works as I expected.

Issue I am having is that when it pulls the data from MySQL, it pulls the same info again and again, I need it to remember the last row or customer ID that it grabbed the last time around, save that ID or Row into a .txt file then pull that same data the next time the script runs so it starts from that row or ID instead of starting from the top again.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import smtplib
import base64
import os
import sys
import csv
from xlsxwriter.workbook import Workbook
import xlwt
import MySQLdb
def sql_run():
ur = 'user' # your username
pd = 'password' # your password
ht = '192.168.1.10' # your host
pt = 3306
db = 'database' # database where your table is stored
#table = 'rma_customer' # table you want to save

con = MySQLdb.connect(user=ur, passwd=pd, host=ht, port=pt, db=db)
cursor = con.cursor()

query = "SELECT cus_id, cus_username FROM database.rma_customer"
query0 = "SELECT cus_firstname, cus_lastname, cus_cell_phone FROM database.rma_customer_details"
query1 = "SELECT cus_address_1 FROM database.rma_customer_address"
query2 = "SELECT cus_city, cus_postcode FROM database.rma_customer_address"
query3 = "SELECT regpro_model_type, regpro_buy_location, regpro_sn FROM database.rma_reg_product"
cursor.execute(query)
workbook = Workbook('outfile.xlsx')
sheet = workbook.add_worksheet("Warranty Info")
headers = ['ID', 'Email', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'Phone', 'Street', 'City', 'Postal', 'Product', 'Store', 'SN']
for i, header in enumerate(headers):
    sheet.write(0, i, header)
for r, row in enumerate(cursor.fetchall()):
    r = r + 1
    for c, col in enumerate(row):

        sheet.write(r, c, col)

cursor.execute(query0)  
for r, row in enumerate(cursor.fetchall()):
    r = r + 1
    for c, col in enumerate(row):

        sheet.write(r, c+2, col)        

cursor.execute(query1)  
for r, row in enumerate(cursor.fetchall()):
    r = r + 1
    for c, col in enumerate(row):

        sheet.write(r, c+5, col)

cursor.execute(query2)  
for r, row in enumerate(cursor.fetchall()):
    r = r + 1
    for c, col in enumerate(row):

        sheet.write(r, c+6, col)

cursor.execute(query3)  
for r, row in enumerate(cursor.fetchall()):
    r = r + 1
    for c, col in enumerate(row):

        sheet.write(r, c+8, col)

cursor.close ()
workbook.close()
con.close ()
sys.exit()
# exit the program



sql_run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add a `row` in the `table`you pull your information from.
2. Pull the `id` (0th's row) as unique identifier
3. Update `row` which has `id` with something like `True` or `False`.
4. Give your query a `condition` that said row must be `True`/ `False`

This way you make sure it stops iterating over the same info.

Programatically:

```
query = "SELECT cus_id, cus_username FROM database.rma_customer WHERE row = 'True'"
...

data = cursor.execute(query)
for col in data:
    id = col[0]
...
cursor.execute("""
    UPDATE table
    SET row= %s
    WHERE id= %s
""", (row, id))
```

The `...` stand for your code. I cannot guess where you want to place the code snippets.

Comment: I couldn't get that to work correctly but what I did was is created a new column in the database and after I pulled the data, it would write to each row for that column and then had a check if exist in that row and if it exists then skip it. You got me in the right direction though, thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear :) If my answer helped you to fix your problem you could mark my answer as accepted